# Why affine variety not vector space variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-schemes

I am new to algebraic geometry. A basic question baffles me: why is the setting the affine space not the vector space?

Comment: The vector space structure doesn't really play a role. To talk about geometric properties of affine plane curves, say, I don't really care that I can add two vectors or that there is an origin.

Comment: The affine space structure similarly does not play much of a role (do we care that we can subtract points to obtain vectors, or translate points by vectors?). I'm actually not sure what a good answer to this question is. Also, sometimes one does wish to use the vector space structure (using constructions like the symmetric algebra $\mathrm{Sym}^\bullet(V^*)$), e.g. for total spaces of vector bundles.